# How to have colored REPL for 'sbt console'?

Tags: scala, sbt

From Scala 2.11.4 onwards you can get a [colored REPL](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3993) by invoking `scala -Dscala.color`. My question is whether it is possible to get the same colored REPL when I call `sbt console` within my SBT project?

Comment: try `dotr` from dotty.. - http://dotty.epfl.ch/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put this into your ~/.sbt/0.13/user.sbt:

```
initialize ~= { _ =>
  val ansi = System.getProperty("sbt.log.noformat", "false") != "true"
  if (ansi) System.setProperty("scala.color", "true")
}
```

Comment: This worked for me! Even though the solution is not very elegant, I like it in that you add it in the repo and then everyone forking the repo will be enjoying the colored REPL.

Comment: OSX/Homebrew: Latest sbt (0.13.12) still only uses Scala 2.10.6 by default, so just add `scalaVersion := "2.11.8"` as a first line right before `initialize ~= ...` to get color support

Answer (score 7):

In the same way:

```
sbt -Dscala.color console
```

This also works if you just invoke `sbt -Dscala.color` and then later jump into `console`.

Comment: Thank! I tried that and I get `Warning: invalid system property 'scala.color'`. What versions of SBT and Scala did you try this on?

Comment: I have sbt 0.13.9 and Scala 2.11.7. It seems to work with older versions as well: `sbt -sbt-version 0.13.5 -scala-version 2.11.4 -Dscala.color` (Those flags are from paulp/sbt-extras though my initial sbt is a vanilla one)

Comment: Still doesn't work for me ... :/. I am on sbt version 0.13.8 and scala 2.11.4.

Comment: What system is giving the warning, scala, the JVM, sbt, its launcher script? Do you maybe have a custom and possibly outdated launcher like an earlier homebrew installation? Could you check if it works with paulp/sbt-extras?

Comment: I think you are onto something. I am on a Mac using a relatively old SBT installation using port (not homebrew).

Comment: Many thanks @knutwalker! I think what you have will work for some properly configured SBT installs, but not for all. I prefer your solution to its simplicity, but the solution from @Twisleton worked (even though I hate it in terms of elegance).

Answer (score 3):

starting from scala 2.12.2, the repl is colored by default; so you just need to set the `scalaVersion` property in `~/.sbt/user.sbt` file:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.2"
```

Comment: sweet! thanks for the comment! I upvoted this since it's great for 2.12.2 users. However, many of us are stuck with 2.11, so I will keep the original one as the officially accepted answer for now.

Comment: I added this answer for new and future users of sbt console, in case they find this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `~/.sbt/0.13/colour.sbt` with:

```
initialize ~= (_ => if (ConsoleLogger.formatEnabled) sys.props("scala.color") = "true")
```